# Handle session timeout in Spring for webservice calls & AJAX calls

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security, session-timeout

I have a set of webservices which are invoked using the URL directly, and some of the webservices are called using AJAX requests from my web application. I am trying to handle session timeout for both these requests but facing some issues. Here's what I have tried and the issues I am facing.

Have added the following to my `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" />
    <logout logout-success-url="${website.url}" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/home?invalid=true" />
</http>
```

1. Now, when I log in to the application and sit idle for one minute (i.e. session timeout configured in `web.xml`, and try to hit any URL (which makes AJAX calls to webservice), I want to redirect the user to login page directly. This is currently not happening.
2. Also, I tried to hit the webservice URL from Chrom extension Postman, I am still getting the results even after the session timeout is passed.

I have referred to similar SO questions and other resources on the internet, but unable to find any resolution. Please suggest if I am missing any configuration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now have handled it this way.

Added session timeout configuration in `web.xml`, and added a `login-page` propert to `form-login` inside `http` config.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Un-comment when authorization is implemented -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login login-page="/rest/invalidateSession"  authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" />
        <logout logout-success-url="${website.url}" />
</http>
```

We could do this since our application login page lies outside web app context. It's a page on a different server.

Inside service `rest/invalidateSession`, it'll return an error which is handled appropirately on the front end.